# How to solve netstat permission denied problem?

Tags: android, emulation, ip-address, messenger, netstat

How can get ip address of a facebook messenger user by using android emulator?
I got message from an unknown user tring to blackmail in a sense (may not be financial) but i dont want him, but he had accessed some of my private info of which revealing may hamper me badly.
I had searched in net, i found that to use **netstat** command in an emulator in android.
I downloaded **Terminal for RNX Linux** app.

I had tried but it says permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question... but:

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#proc-net-filesystem):

On devices that run Android 10 or higher, apps cannot access /proc/net, which includes information about a device's network state.

So you probably might need to root your device

EDIT:
Also, I don't think running the command will help you a lot, you might get the IP of the server messenger uses, but not the person's IP